# Kubernetes - Ingress TCP service SSL Termination

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm doing SSL termination using Ingress for HTTPS traffic. But I also want to achieve the same thing for Custom Port (http virtual host). For example `https://example.com:1234` should go to `http://example.com:1234`

Nginx Ingress has a `ConfigMap` where we can expose custom ports. But SSL termination doesn't work here.

Any work around? I wonder If I could redirect the incoming `https` using .htaccess instead.

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: tcp-services
      namespace: ingress-nginx
    data:
      1234: "test-web-services/httpd:1234"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: port-1234
      port: 1234
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 1234
```

Comment: Hello, SSL Termination for TCP services are not a feature directly supported by `nginx-ingress`. There are a workaround in this [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/636#issuecomment-749026036). Also as your backend is HTTP based I do think you could use port `1234` to be send to `targetPort: 443` and then `Ingress controller` will terminate your `HTTPS` and send `HTTP` request to your backend. Have you tried this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SSL Termination` for TCP traffic is not a feature directly supported by `nginx-ingress`.

It is more widely described in this Github issue:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Ingress-nginx: Issues: [nginx] Support SSL for TCP](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/636)*

You can also find in this thread that some people were successful in implementing a workaround allowing them to support terminating `SSL` with `TCP` services. Specifically:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Ingress-nginx: Issues: [nginx] Support SSL for TCP: Comment 749026036](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/636#issuecomment-749026036)*

---

As your example featured the "downgrade" from `HTTPS` communication to `HTTP` it could be beneficiary to add that you can alter the way that `NGINX Ingress Controller` connects to your `backend`. Let me elaborate on that.

Please consider this as a workaround:

By default your `NGINX Ingress Controller` will connect to your backend with `HTTP`. This can be changed with following annotation:

- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol:`

Citing the official documentation:

> Using backend-protocol annotations is possible to indicate how NGINX should communicate with the backend service. (Replaces secure-backends in older versions) Valid Values: HTTP, HTTPS, GRPC, GRPCS, AJP and FCGI
>
> **By default NGINX uses HTTP.**
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress-nginx: User guide: Nginx configuration: Annotations: Backend protocol](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol)*

In this particular example the request path will be following:

- `client` -- (HTTP**S**:443) --> `Ingress controller` (TLS Termination) -- (HTTP:service-port) --> `Service` ----> `Pod`

---

#### The caveat

You can use the `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` to send the traffic from port `1234` to either `80`/`443` of your `Ingress Controller`. This would make `TLS` termination much easier but it would force the client to use **only one** protocol. For example:

```yaml
    - name: custom
      port: 1234
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 443
```

This excerpt from `nginx-ingress` `Service` could be used to forward the **`HTTPS`** traffic to your `Ingress Controller` where the request would be `TLS terminated` and forwarded as `HTTP` to your `backend`. Forcing the `HTTP` through that port would yield error code `400: Bad request`.

In this particular example the request path will be following:

- `client` -- (HTTP**S**:1234) --> `Ingress controller` (TLS Termination) -- (HTTP:service-port) --> `Service` ----> `Pod`

Answer (score 1):

A detail that is often overlooked is that there exist two different nginx ingress controllers for Kubernetes:

- the "default" [nginx-ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx), which is developed by the Kubernetes community and mostly referred to indeed only supports TLS termination for http
- the "corporate" [nginx-ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) version by the company NGINX however **does support TLS termination** on TCP level

For more details on the differences between the two see [this blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/guide-to-choosing-ingress-controller-part-4-nginx-ingress-controller-options/) by the nginx corporation. As you can gather from the blog there exists both a free and open source edition and a commercial edition ("nginx PLUS").

With the nginx corporate version (open source / free) you can achieve the TLS termination on TCP level by deploying a [TransportServer](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/transportserver-resource/) resource.

I managed to get this to work with a MQTT broker as follows (using [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/) for TLS cert management):

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1alpha1
kind: TransportServer
metadata:
  name: "my-mqtt-ingress"
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "{{- .Values.global.clusterIssuerName -}}"
spec:
  listener:
      name: mqtts
      protocol: TCP
  tls:
    secret: "broker-cert-secret"
  upstreams:
  - name: mqtt-broker
    service: "broker-service"
    port: 1883
  action:
    pass: mqtt-broker
```

In this case I had to first define the `mqtts` protocol and enable cert-manager usage during the installation of the nginx-ingress controller via the [global configuration](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/globalconfiguration-resource/) object:

```
  globalConfiguration:
    create: true
    spec:
      listeners:
        - name: "mqtts"
          port: 8883
          protocol: "TCP"
  enableCertManager: true
```